# Using Selenium IDE how do you get field values that are dynamic each time the script is run

Tags: selenium-ide

Using Selenium IDE how do you get field values that are dynamic each time the script is run i.e Field = "this" next time the scripts runs Field = "that". The script needs to type that value into the text field before moving on. How is this done? I am bit of newbie I just need a piece of code to get me started. Thanks for helping out.

I use another tool where I simply supply a regexp like jmeter regexp extractor. works miracles but selenium I am finding it difficult.

Answer (score 3):

use this code and let me know whether it work or not, you have to store value of text id then write value manually in the text vox

```
 pause      | 1000
 Storeeval  | prompt("enter the value") | value
 type       | id=fieldText              | ${value}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestions. Actually after having tried the suggestion to use storeText to no avail. I tried storeValue of the field into a variable then used the variable with the Type command to input the dynamic value into the field. Worked like a charm! Thanks to all for pointing me into the right direction.

Comment: how? I don't see a link to accept answers. Yours and the MikeH below helped me to solve my problem. Again thanks to the both of you.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the storeText command - this can store the value as a variable and then call that variable using the type command for the relevant field eg:

Command  |  Target  |  Value

storeText  |  id=field  | fieldText

type  | id=fieldText | ${fieldText}

Comment: Thanks very much I will try that. sounds like it will work! I have only been using selenium for like a day. I am trying to figure things out quickly. Your advise really helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the field is textbox, this worked for me:

```
storeValue | id=field      | fieldValue
type       | id=inputValue | ${fieldValue}
```